# Mix Gardiant and a value together

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have a value in Sass with `$mainColor:#070517;`
I want to know what is the best way to put this Gardiant script instead of that color?

````
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)

```
@mixin my-gradient {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29);
background: linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29);
}
```

```
div {
@include my-gradient;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, where should I mention the mainColor also on my code?

Comment: $mainColor is just a variable that holds that specific colour value, so it can be applied anywhere in your stylesheet that needs that colour: color, background-color, border-color, etc.  You can't assign the gradient mixin to that variable because that would not be valid css

Comment: What is the alternative way to do that? because I have many components on my website and want to make all of them have the same gradient style.

Comment: You'll probably have to edit each of the components to include the mixin if you want more than one rule. The only way you can reuse your variable is if you give it the value "linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29)" which may not cover all browsers

Comment: You are great! Thank you